# Splunk submit button (submitButton) does not refresh dashboard if no inputs are changed

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk, splunk-dashboard

I have a dashboard with a submit button (submitButton). The search isn't run until the button is pressed which is exactly what I want (the search takes a long time). I don't want the search starting as the user changes the other dropdowns (time), environment (Prod vs. QA), etc.

HOWEVER, sometimes it would be nice to hit the submit button and perform the search again without changing any of the other fields (time, environment, etc.).  In this case the submit button does nothing! I can tell the underlying data has changed via searches, but the dashboard is not updated. Simply changing any of the fields, doing a search, and then changing them back and searching again solves the problem, but surely the submit button should just work w/o this workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Each panel in the dashboard should (automatically) have a refresh button you can click to refresh the display without changing inputs.

Comment: Thanks again RichG. I was sort of hoping for a Refresh button for the entire dashboard.  Or better, the Submit button really should refresh everything even if none of the search parameters have changed. As it is, it's sort of dangerous. You hit Submit and conclude, "Hmm. I guess no more new data. Nothing changed".

Comment: Consider visiting https://ideas.splunk.com to suggest one or both of those ideas.

Comment: @RichG  Please put your comment as answer so I can select.  I'll consider submitting a request. Meanwhile, I'm using your idea and it's solving the initial problem I posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each panel in the dashboard should (automatically) have a refresh button you can click to refresh the display without changing inputs.

Comment: I meant put this in your answer :) 
Each panel in the dashboard should (automatically) have a refresh button you can click to refresh the display without changing inputs

Comment: Because that is a solution.  It may not be an ideal solution (in my opinion) but it does answer what I asked for. And you answered first.

Answer (score 2):

If "nothing" has changed, then Submit is *supposed* to "do nothing".

If you want to refresh the page *with all the parameters as set*, you should be able to click the URL bar and press <kbd>return</kbd> (so long as there are no hidden tokens, they'll all get set in the query portion of the URL).

Answer (score 2):

I've browsed through Internet and  found some solution that with some modifications worked for me fine

```
<form>
..
     <html>
       <style>
         div.fieldset.dashboard-form-globalfieldset div.dashboard-element.html.dashboard-element-html {
        display: inline-block;
           }
       </style>
       <a href="<<dasboardID>>?form.cust_str=$cust_str$&amp;form.time.earliest=$time.earliest$&amp;form.time.latest=$time.latest$&amp;form.env=$env$&amp;form.proj=$proj$" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh</a>
     </html>
...
<form/>
```

so basiclu im refreshing page with all of its attributes  and passing attributes values form current ones  chosen using tokens. splunk code didn't like & so replaced it with & and it worked fine. <> - can be found in your splunk page address.

Comment: Can you please specify the steps to get the `dasboardID` ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is intended behavior.

I also wish that the submit button would rerun dashboard searches. I opened a post on Splunk ideas about this issue:
https://ideas.splunk.com/ideas/EID-I-739
If you have a splunk.com account, you can vote for this idea.